# Return off a static, recursive Java method doesn't work

Tags: java, recursion

I try to implement an Sudoku-Solver. I am invoking the method printSoluition(board) and it should print out the solution, if one exists or null.

I am trying it with an example that has one solution. But it always returns null.

My Code:

```
static void printSolution(SudokuBoard board) {

    SudokuBoard resultBoard = findSolution(board);

    if(resultBoard != null) {
        resultBoard.print();
    }
}

static SudokuBoard findSolution(SudokuBoard board) {

    if (board.isSolved()) {
        return board;

    } else {

        int nextEmptyField = getNextFreeIndex(board);

        if (nextEmptyField != -1) {

            int[] kandidaten = board.getCandidates(nextEmptyField);

            for (int i = 0; i < kandidaten.length; i++) {

                SudokuBoard newBoard = board.set(nextEmptyField,
                        kandidaten[i]);

                return findSolution(newBoard);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion with backtracking implementation is incorrect, because your `for` loop never goes past the first candidate.

You need to change the loop to return only when a solution is found:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kandidaten.length; i++) {
    SudokuBoard newBoard = board.set(freiesNaechstesFeld, kandidaten[i]);
    SudokuBoard solution = findSolution(newBoard);
    if (solution != null {
        return solution;
    }
}
```

Now all candidates in all invocation levels will be tried, so eventually you would end up with a solution (assuming, of course, that your "helper" methods that find and set candidates work fine).

Comment: I can't understand your "because your for loop never goes past the first candidate".. Can you describe it a little bit more, please

Comment: @user2438518 Your current loop has an **unconditional** `return` statement in it, that is why it never really iterates. So if the first candidate that you pick on any level does not lead to a solution, you are bound to return `null`.